# For + -ing verb (purpose)

Tags: infinitives, continuous-aspect

Page 200 of the Collins English Usage reads

> You do not use 'for' with an '-ing' form when you saying why someone
> does something. You do not say, for example, '*He went to the city for
> finding work*'.

However, the following example is given in the same book:
*"I recommend hill running for strengthening thighs.*

Isn't this a contradiction?

Comment: "The difference is that "hill running" is a noun phrase; the purpose is attached to the noun phrase.

_I recommend hill running for strengthening thighs_; 
_*I run up hills for strengthening thighs_ ; 
_I run up hills to strengthen my thighs_."

Comment: Also compare: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/24553/how-can-i-decide-when-to-use-for-ing-or-to-infinitive-in-a-sentence

Comment: The prepositional _for_ is not a marker of purpose; rather it's part of  the verbal construction _recommend `X` for `Y`_. For instance, _It's recommended for treating gout and also strengthening thighs._